# "Промостойка" или "промо-стойка"?

Tags: морфология, слитно-дефис

Слово промостойка появилось в языке сравнительно недавно, какому правилу на ваш взгляд подчиняется его написание? Как сложносочиненное существительное с соединительной буквой О или как иноязычная приставка к существительному, и в таком случае написание через дефис?

Answer (score 1):

*Промо-* – первая часть сложная снов, пишется слитно. Я с трудом представляю, как можно принять её за приставку, но даже и при этом фантастическом допущении нормативным всё равно оставалось бы только слитное написание.

Answer (score 1):

Промостойка (сложносокращённое слово, от *промоутерский + стойка*); промоакция (*промоутерский + акция*), промопрограмма (*промоутерский + программа*) и т. п.

Comment: Вы правы, я уже нашла ответ на этот вопрос, здесь подчиняется именно правилу образование от словосочетания с подчинительной связью, спасибо